# Citrix Error: Your user profile was not loaded correctly

Tags: windows-server-2003, citrix

We get this error from out citrix server:

```
Your user profile was not loaded correctly!
You have been logged on with a temporary profile.
Changes you make to this profile will be lost when you log off.
Please see the event log for details or contact your administrator.
```

I am well aware there is a workaround by Citrix, that can be found [here](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX126690), but that doesn't permanently fix our issue.  It seems to come back.

Any idea why that happens? Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Citrix version is 4.5 running on Windows 2003 x32

**EDIT 14.IX.2012 @ 16.03 CT**

I am sorry, let me clarify, it happens to some users, not all and not all the time.

Comment: It's not clear - do all your users get this error, all the time? Or just occasionally? Sounds like something is screwing with the permissions on the TSprofile such that Citrix can't load it

Comment: I am sorry, let me clarify, it happens to some users, not all and not all the time.

Comment: Check if AV Software has still access to some files.
Running Citrix Server within VMware? Shared Folders within the guest tools deactivated?
Check the event log to see which file hangs.

Comment: Yes, Citrix Server is running within VMware.  No files hang.  AV software is not accessing then.

Comment: If it is always the same users, is there an AD group or GPO which is true for all of these users and not for others?

Comment: @boburob Different users, but some do repeat.  I am not sure what you mean.  We do have different security AD groups...

Comment: Are the permissions/GPO settings for the users that repeatedly have issues the same or is there a particular setting which is the same.

Answer (score 1):

I would advice you delete the user profile and then make a little adjustment to the profile username (Meaning do a rename of the username so it creates a fresh profile not minding the former username).

Regards

Comment: Yeah, we followed http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX126690.  It's kind of what you are suggesting.

Comment: I use citrix and that is the solution I use... btw I never went to their site to check for solutions... lol

Answer (score 0):

Rebooting the server every night will also help with this. The registry hives will get released after the reboot. 
Wall